# Check for each -nth item in for loop Twig

Tags: symfony, for-loop, twig, jquery-gmap3

I'm starting to get to know Twig, but how can you check for the first, second, third, ... item of a for-loop in Twig?

I would like to add a gmap for each address, each with class gmap_one, gmap_two, gmap_three,....

```
    {% for company in companies %}
    <li>
            <p>{{ company.Company() }}</p>
            <p>{{ company.Contactperson() }}</p>
            <p>{{ company.Phone() }}</p>

            <div class="gmap gmap_one">
            <script>
                    var gmap_address_one = {{ company.Address() }};
            </script>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
{% set gmap = ['one', 'two', 'three'] %}
{% for company in companies %}
<li>
        <p>{{ company.Company() }}</p>
        <p>{{ company.Contactperson() }}</p>
        <p>{{ company.Phone() }}</p>

        <div class="gmap gmap_{{ gmap[ loop.index-1] }}">
        <script>
                var gmap_address_{{ gmap[ loop.index-1] }} = {{ company.Address() }};
        </script>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can use the loop variable  `loop.index0` That return the current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed). Has described in the
 [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable). So you can remove the `-1` expression